# Propensity Score in R

Tags: r, matching

I am working with the propensity score and I have a question about it.

I am using matchit() from library(MatchIt) in the following way:
m.out = matchit(a ~ b, data = propensity_data, method = "nearest")

b is a propability, so it is between 0 and 1. The code is:

```
a<-round(runif(100))
b<-runif(100)
data_table<-data.frame(a,b)

m.out= matchit(a ~ b, data = data_table, method = "nearest")
matchlist <- match.data(m.out)
```

Why is there a difference between b and "distance" in "matchlist"? Is the matching working with "distance" or b? How can I match the control data with the treated units directly on b? The last question is the main one.

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

The matching is working with b in a logistic regression framework so the difference between the propensity score b and the distance is just due to the link function for the model.

As you can see from this they are pretty much perfectly correlated. Therefore doesn't matter which one you match on the result will be the same.

```
> cor(matchlist$b, matchlist$distance)
[1] -0.9999959
```

So in answer to your question you have already matched directly on b (and distance).

Comment: Okay, thank you. But how can I do the matching directly on b? I want to make it a little bit more clean.

Comment: Sorry I don't know how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

As @Adam mentioned in the other answer, by default `matchit()` performs propensity score matching with propensity scores estimated from a logistic regression of the treatment on the covariates specified in the model. To perform matching on `b` instead, just set `distance = data_table$b` in the call to `matchit()`.